# SQL Query did not show result on Data Block Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms, oracle-fusion-middleware

I want show SQL Query Data into Data Block Through When-Button-Pressed.

**Code:**

```
DECLARE
 p_cnic VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN

 p_cnic := 'SELECT cnicno FROM hof WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k)';
 :we_group_hof_k.CNIC_NO := p_cnic;
END;
```

The data block "CNIC_NO" Data Type is VARCHAR

When I pressed the button then I am getting error

```
FRM-40735: WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED Trigger raised unhandled exception
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You just need to use an `INTO` clause with a `SELECT` statement without `quotes` as :*

```
BEGIN    
  SELECT cnicno
    INTO :we_group_hof_k.CNIC_NO 
    FROM hof 
   WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k);     
 EXCEPTION WHEN no_data_found THEN null;
END;
```

- *In your case, no need to use a local variable ( `p_cnic` ), e.g. you
  can directly assign value to the field. If you really needed, prefer
  defining as `p_cnic hof.cnicno%type` instead, in which no matter what the data type of the column.*
- *Add Exception handling against the possibility to raise no_data_found
  exception*

> If you need to bring multiple records, using an `SELECT .. INTO`
>   clause is not suitable, since you'd get
>
> `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than one requested number`
>
> in such a case.

*Prefer using a cursor instead, against the situation above :*

```
BEGIN   
     go_block('myblock'); 
     first_record;
  for c in
          (
           SELECT cnicno
             FROM hof 
            WHERE cnicno IN (SELECT cnic_no FROM we_group_hof_k)
          )     
  loop
    :we_group_hof_k.CNIC_NO := c.cnicno;
     next_record;
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: FRM-40735: WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED Trigger raised unhandled exception

Comment: @RamizTariq  "Trigger raised unhandled exception ... " must continue with some more declaration including a code prefixed as `ORA-`

Comment: FRM-40735: WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED Trigger raised unhandled exception ORA-01422